# Не удается поставить главную активность

Tags: xml, android

В манифесте написано, что 1 класс должен вылезать первее 2, так как указан в манифесте, но на деле почему-то первым окном вылезает 2 класс, почему?

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".List_item"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Comment: полный код манифеста в студию

Comment: а вот тут у вас, случаем, не выставлено ничего?
http://take.ms/mYcTG

Comment: В Эклипсе у меня запускается активность по дефолту

Comment: @altermim, посмотрите настройки эклипса, возможно, там уже прописана первая в лаунчере.

Answer (score 1):

Код у Вас верный. Проверьте лаунчер Вашей среды разработки. Скорее всего дело в нем.

Пример лаунчера с классом, что нужно отобразить первым - [ссылка на картинку из Google Pictures](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/51184627/06-01.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1364283707000)

Comment: А это где? У меня эклипс)

Comment: @altermim, следуйте по пунктам:

Run - Run Configuration - "Название Вашего приложения" - "вкладка Android(справа вверху будет) - Launch <- Сюда ввести/выбрать нужный класс.

Comment: @altermim, по возможности переходите на Android Studio или Intellij IDEA. 
ссылка на Android Studio:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/12/android-studio-10.html

и на Intellij IDEA:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

P.S.: Данный софт абсолютно бесплатен для всех.